# Latex not displayed correctly in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, jupyter

When executing the following code in python using jupyter/ipython, the Latex symbols are not displayed correctly. Any Idea why this could be?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

x = np.linspace(0,3)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.title(r'$\beta \rho \lambda \xi$',fontsize=30)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: cannot reproduce. Can you add your matplotlib version?

Comment: Matplotlib is version 1.5.2rc2, jupyter version 4.1.0

Comment: Hmh, 1.5.2 seems to work for me as well. Maybe a simple reinstall will do?

Comment: Probably yes, I will try that later

Answer (score 2):

IPython notebook uses [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org) to render LaTeX inside html/markdown. Just put your LaTeX math inside $$.

```
$$c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$$
```

[image]

You have to write :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,3)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.title(r'$$\beta \rho \lambda \xi$$',fontsize=30)

plt.show()
```

### --------------------

Or you can display LaTeX / Math output from Python, as seen towards the end of the [notebook tour](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/1.x/examples/notebooks/Part%205%20-%20Rich%20Display%20System.ipynb) :

```
from IPython.display import display, Math, Latex
display(Math(r'F(k) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{2\pi i k} dx'))
```

[image]

### ---------------------

Other kind of solution :

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
mpl.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r'\usepackage{amsmath}'] #for \text command

x = np.linspace(0,3)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.title(r'$text{\beta \rho \lambda \xi}$',fontsize=30)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, but this gives me the error "TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable". Seems like I cannot place double $'s

Comment: I did not know that, that's actually very helpful. (+1) However, it does not solve my original problem as far as I can see. (Making matplotlib labels/titles with LaTex in python).

Comment: @physicsGuy I don't work on jupiter/notebook but I knew that this solution worked. I will see with my jupiter friend user if he has an other solution ;)

Comment: Maybe other solution : `plt.title(r"\TeX\ is Number "
          r"$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{-e^{i\pi}}{2^n}$!",
          fontsize=16, color='gray')`

Comment: It seems as something in my system is not up to date, as I get the error "ParseFatalException: Unknown symbol: \displaystyle (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)", when using your line.

Comment: @physicsGuy I edited a last time my answer at the end with an other way to solve your problem. Try this. If it doesn't work, unfortunately I have not idea :/